# How can i add single app in two organisations? client-team and dev-team

Tags: ios, crash, xcode6, crashlytics

In my iOS App, i want two separate teams for Crashlytics reporting. One for internal testing and other for client team. During Development, if crashes will come then it should report in dev-team and if app will be live then crashes should be report in client-team. dev-team and client-team can have common members. How can i achieve this behaviour.

According to mine, if i create two organisations and register my app in two organisations and just switch the API keys in the app when i needed; I think it can be the solution for it. Need your suggestion/solution; Many thanks.

If any other solution exists for this problem then your direction will be more anticipated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Crashlytics differentiates apps using the bundle ID, you can just change that.  In order to make your bundle ID dynamic, go to your info.plist file for your project and change the **Bundle Identifier** key to the value:

> com.yourcompany.${CUSTOM_BUNDLE_ID}

Then in your **build settings**, add a user-defined key called (you guessed it):

> CUSTOM_BUNDLE_ID

And then you can specify a different setting for debug, release, distribution:
[image: Example user-defined setting]
This will let Crashlytics register different "apps" for the same binary.

To make things even easier, use the same approach to specify a custom product name so that apps will appear with different names and devs/qa can easily identify what "version" of an app they're testing.

We generally don't upload our dev binaries to Crashlytics because we build so many times and we QA on builds from our CI server.  That's why we actually specify the product name and bundle ID dynamically at build time on our CI server.  This allows (for bigger projects) many parallel apps with different bundle IDs to be distributed/tracked by Crashlytics and all it takes is a new build config.

Comment: Thanks for response. It will work but how can we filter members? I want crashes should just go to dev-team for dev build. For this, i think we need separate organisation. Thanks

Comment: All crashes go to Crashlytics.  The only difference is in which members can see which crashes.  Each member can modify that setting in their own Crashlytics settings easily, where they will see dev vs release vs distro builds as different apps.  For members who are part of both dev and client, then they will see both crashes for both apps.  You don't want different organizations, you want different apps. || Also, you should probably err on the side of not completely blocking the info because you never know when member of one team might want to see info from another team.